# LiDAR download - ASC file to QGIS - Rasterize ->Extract -> COntour - Export to Google Earth Pro

Tags: kml, contour

I am trying to create a 50cm contour map using QGIS and then export it as KML to Google Earth Pro. When I get to Earth and import the KML file I am left with random red lines around the globe.

The process I am following

1. https://environment.data.gov.uk/DefraDataDownload/?Mode=survey
2. Polygon select area
3. Download tiles
4. I am selecting LiDAR Composite DTM, year 2019, resolution DTM 1M, tile ref NY96ne
5. That gives me files which are in various other formats but I want .asc files.
   So
6. I have then selected LIDAR Tiles DTM 2012 1M NY96ne. Turns out they are a a series of TIFs and XML documents. Dont like the look of those.
7. So, I'll try LiDAR Composite DTM 2017 1M NY96ne. These show up in Explorer as Adobe Reader files, tho when opening in Adobe Reader it says the file cannot be opened as .asc is not compatible with Adobe Reader. So it appears they are .asc files [image: ASC fils]
8. I have then opened QGIS Desktop 3.16.3 (NOT with the GRASS extension) and added in some tiles ny9568_DTM_1M and ny9569_DTM_1M, ny9468 and ny9469 and ny9668 and ny9669.
9. I did add a few more tiles but there are some data gaps in the data so I've removed those layers. apart from ny9469.
10. I have then selected all the tiles in the Layers panel and gone to Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Build Virtual Raster. This brings up the Build Virtual Raster dialogue
11. Up pops the Select Layers dialogue so I have selected all the layers I require
12. I've then set the resolution to high. This is different from my previous attempts where the res was set at average.
13. I then hit run, giving me a 'Virtual' layer.

14.I have unselected the other layers now, and only have the Virtual layer selected. Then I have gone Raster->Extraction->Contour and have changed the contour interval to 0.5 Hit Run [image: contour extraction run view]

15. I've then right clicked on the 'Contour' layer [image: export] and then Export -> Save Feature As bringing up this dialogue box [image: Save Feature dialogue]. I have added a file name and
    changed the CRS from Invalid Projection to Project CPS: EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 [image: WGS 84] and saved it to my desktop.
16. I have then opened Google Earth Pro (desktop), clicked on File -> Open -> and then selected the file I have just saved (Contours 22jan morning attempt). It opened up and the image I get is this [image: Utter mayhem]
17. I accept defeat and go for caffeine. I must have spent about 20 hours on this now and I seem to get no further forward. There must be a glitch somewhere in amongst all this but that goes well beyond my capabilities on these tippytappy machines. I feel so close yet so far.

Can anyone point me in a better direction?

Comment: your projection should be EPSG:27700

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Ian. I have tried changing the projection to EPSG:27700, QGIS gives a warning symbol with message 'Used a ballpark transform from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:27700'

Comment: Opening the KML file in Earth Pro still causes red line mayhem.

Comment: No, your data comes in as 27700 this is the one time you should use setcrs

Comment: I'm somewhat confused now. Are you saying that the downloads from environment.data.gov.uk should come in as 27700? Or where do I need to make a change in the process that I followed (as detailed in the OP)? I've had a look at the LiDAR layer properties and there is no CRS value given.

Comment: Yes you need to set the crs of all the asc files to 27700, - see https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools,/projections,/itches/2017/10/20/adding-prj.html for a quick way to do it